# Associating Parent Workflow to Structure Group

Tags: workflow

I am creating Tridion structure group using core service in c# as below

ServiceClient.Create(structureGroupData, new ReadOptions() { LoadFlags = LoadFlags.Expanded })

I want to associate workflow which parent has when creating new structure group using above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use all process associations from parent publication you can set `ShareProcessAssociations` on publication to true. Be aware that all process associations will be shared - for components, pages, templates, etc.

If you want to do it only once, for this particular item you can set:

```
structureGroupData.PageBundleProcess = new LinkToProcessDefinitionData{IdRef = porcessDefinitionId};
structureGroupData.PageProcess = new LinkToProcessDefinitionData{IdRef = porcessDefinitionId};
```